# Django Pass additional parameters from a link to another view

Tags: python, django

I have a page `drag.html`which is served at this URL
`http://localhost:8000/dashboard?wid=ca1480f&ref_url=localhost&adpart=left` this page have a link

```
<a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/save" class="btn">Save Reward</a>
```

when a user click this link it will redirect to a `SaveRewardview` where i want to save all the information present in link i.e `wid=ca1480f&ref_url=localhost&adpart=left`

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^dashboard$', login_required(CouponPageView.as_view()), name='dashboard'),
url(r'^dashboard/save$', login_required(SaveRewardView.as_view()), name=''),
```

**model.py**

```
class SaveReward(models.Model):
  widget = EmbeddedModelField(Widget)
  campaign = EmbeddedModelField(Campaign)
  coupon_part = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  saved_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.widget.widget_name
```

**Views.py**

```
class SaveRewardView(TemplateView):

  #Here how i will get wid , ref_url, adpart which is present in url parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly give parameters in url like this.

```
<a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/?{{request.META.QUERY_STRING}}" class="btn">Save Reward</a>
```

url is:

```
url(r'^dashboard/$', login_required(CouponPageView.as_view()), name='dashboard'),
```

Comment: you can set these dynamically as well like : href="/dashboard/?wid={{your value1}}&ref_url={{equest.get_host}}&adpart={{your value2}}"

Comment: But how i will access those values ? They are only available in url

Comment: You can us request.get_full_path() in your views or also you should use request.GET from find your parameters and return these from your views to templates. like wid = request.GET.get('wid'), and then 
return render_to_response('vista_ads.html', {'wid':wid},
context_instance=RequestContext(request)).

Comment: I have just update my post. you can use href="/dashboard/?{{request.META.QUERY_STRING}}" for all parameters.